# Flask - 404 Not found : The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I'm completely new to Flask. As a beginner I'm trying to print 'Hello World' on a web page. When run this Flask application, the browser throwing me a `404` error. It says `The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Here is my `__init__.py` :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import app
```

My `routes.py` file:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

And my `microApp.py` file:

`from app import app`

Here is my working directory:

```
My Project/
  venv/
  app/
    __init__.py
    routes.py
  microApp.py
```

I set `FLASK_APP = microApp.py` and tried to run Flask. But the browser is throwing me an error.

Please anyone help me, I'm a noob. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would combine it all together into 1 file and run it that way.

Comment: Yeah, the Flask documentation page makes this thing easy. But I'm following a tutorial and trying to go with them.

Comment: If your tutorial is making you make 3 separate files each with 10  lines of code, then it is the one at fault. There will be weird imports and stuff, and it will just make things confusing.

Comment: @coderman1234, Though it's a tedious task to write 10 lines code for a simple 'Hello World' print, but I want to clear the concept how the flow of code working.

Comment: So would you like a server that does print "Hello world"?

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access

Comment: @phileinSophos, ```http://127.0.0.1:5000/``` or ```http://127.0.0.1:5000/index```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are importing `app` that means your basically importing `__init__.py` file.
The `__init__.py` files are modules that initialize the packages.[modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)
So in your `__init__.py` file you importing again 'app'. Here you have to call 'routes'.

Answer (score 0):

A server that does print "Hello world":

```py
from flask import Flask 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route('/index')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world!"

app.run('127.0.0.1', port=5500)
```